# How to assign a macro to Sort & Filter in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

Well, I know nothing about assigning Macros (and I'm hoping not to anytime soon) so I'm hoping to do this as painless as possible.

I want it that, for example a picture, when I click it, it will automatically Sort & Filter all of Column 'C'.

I am being rather specific, so I do understand if this can't be done.
Thanks for anyones' help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done. It's just a matter of how much you are prepared to stretch and learn.

A starting point would be to record a macro: Open your workbook, click the icon to record a macro.

[image]

Click through the steps to sort and filter your data. Then click to stop the macro recorder.

[image]

You can now insert a shape on the sheet, right-click the shape and assign the macro to the shape.

[image]

You can also assign a macro to a picture, instead of a shape, and the macro will run when the picture is clicked.

If you need more details about what the macro should actually do, please start a new question and post the requirements for the actual macro.

Comment: Oh My Goodness, you have saved my Excel life forever. I never knew Macros were so easy! Thank you SO much!